# How do I set a random number between two variables in batch?

Tags: batch-file, variables

I am trying to get a random number between 25 and 50, but be able to change it by changing the variables, what is the code for this?

ive tried all of these solutions:
set /a var=(%random%*%maxvar%/32768)+%minvar
set /a var=%random% %% %maxvar% + %minvar%
and plenty of other solutions ive found.

```
set %maxvar%=50
set %minvar%=25

set /a var=%random% %% %maxvar% %minvar%
```

I would do the same in my code but want to replace the 50 and 25 with the variables.

I thought the output would end up somewhere between the two variables but it just ends up with either negative numbers or numbers above 50.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable name doesn't need to contain `%`:

```
set min_val=25
set max_val=50

set /a rand_num=%RANDOM% * (%max_val% - %min_val% + 1) / 32768 + %min_val%
```